# Run a method once before and an after every test in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

so here is my problem

I made some kind of python win32com excel manager, I made unit-testing
However each test is opening/closing excel, an excel don't like that (52 tests).

What I'd like is the following thing :

```
manager= Win32comExcelManager()
manager.openExcel()

test1
test2
'''
test52

manager.closeExcel()
```

However I have been unable to do so, I know that it's a bad practice because each test is suposed to be independant but here it seems to be the right thing to do.

How could I do this?

framework : unittest

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you put it into `setUpClass`/`tearDownClass`? As long as you're not actually testing the opening and closing within the tests in that class, or relying on the subsequent order of the tests, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Which test framework are you using?

Comment: unittest, setUpClass is called before instanciation so I cannot put my manager in the class property

Comment: I don't understand why you can't put the manager in the class setup.